# jetty java web start standalone

Tags: jetty, java-web-start

I have (jetty) java web start standalone code something like this. I need to add SSL Certificate for the same.

```java
    org.mortbay.util.Log.instance().add(new TomeLogSink(NAME));

    server = new HttpServer();

    SocketListener listener = new SocketListener();
    listener.setPort(port);
    server.addListener(listener);

    // context to handle all other request including servlets
    HttpContext context = new HttpContext();
    context.setContextPath(HttpConstants.HTTP_CONTEXT_PATH);
    context.setResourceBase(HttpConstants.HTTP_PROVIDENT_ROOT);

    //handler for servlets
    servletHandler = new ServletHandler();

    addServlet("*.jnlp", JnlpServlet.class);
    addServlet("/index.htm", IndexServlet.class);
    addServlet("/index.html", IndexServlet.class);

    CcAdminServiceImpl cc = (CcAdminServiceImpl) RegistryManager.get(
            CcAdminService.REGISTERED_NAME);
    cc.createWebContent(this);

    //handler for static content
    ResourceHandler handler = new ResourceHandler();
    handler.setDirAllowed(false);
    handler.setAcceptRanges(false);

    context.addHandler(servletHandler);
    context.addHandler(handler);
    context.addHandler(new NotFoundHandler());

    //setup and start the server
    server.addContext(createStaticContext(
            HttpConstants.HTTP_HELP_PATH,
            HttpConstants.HTTP_HELP_ROOT));

    server.addContext(context);

    server.start();
```

Comment: `org.mortbay.*` indicates an ancient version of Jetty, long since EOL (End of Life).  Consider upgrading to something recent, stable, and (more importantly) supported.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.